# PPPoE in Linux Mint 16

Tags: linux-mint, ethernet, mac-address, pppoe, spoofing

I use a broadband connection in windows 7 to connect to internet. I use a spoofed MAC id on the same Windows 7 laptop because my internet is MAC binded to my desktop computer. Now I am trying to achieve same on Linux Mint 16. I used `sudo pppoeconf` and configured it. And ran `plog` but it shows:

> Remote message: login incorrect
>    PAP authentication failed

I am sure I am using correct credentials. So it must be the wrong MAC address. I tried going through the "network connections" window and added a DSL connection with proper MAC id in "cloned mac address" field, but then I am unable to activate this connection. I don't know how to activate this connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that your

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

looks something like

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
# clone mac address so we can get in net as instructed by IT
hwaddress ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

next be sure you reset your broadband router (clearing DHCP/ARP tables) before powering up your Mint

if you are still in trouble you can run the following commands before the next login attempt

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: I tried the second method and it worked